# spring boot performance and overall experience

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8

I really like how easy it is to use spring boot. Has any used spring boot in their production apps? If so what were some pros/cons and gotchas while using it ? What is the performance of using spring boot's embedded container ?

Thanks
-Parshu

Comment: This is not a question that has a direct answer.  This is more of an opinion seeking post.

Answer (score 10):

Spring Boot is not for microservices as it is too big and too slow. We are joking it can do miniservices as it still inside a servlet container. If you are aiming to deploy your microservices into docker container than you don't need another container which adds latency. I have done a performance test between spring boot and light-4j framework and light-4j is 44 times faster than spring boot. The source code for both can be found at

https://github.com/networknt/microservices-framework-benchmark

Also here is a third party benchmarks from techempower

https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/previews/round15/

Comment: I confirmt light4j is probably best framework I have seen so far providing complete microservice development platform.

Comment: Thanks @kensai for your kind words. We were so focused on the large scale deliveries in Financial and Government sectors with partners in the past and will spend more time to build the community in the future. The document site consolidation is the first step to bring more people on board.

Answer (score 0):

I currently use spring-boot in 3 of my production apps, and another one is on its way. Spring-boot is good because it aims that you should write code for only your business logic, nothing else. If you want to use it as a monolithic app, i suggest that to not use embedded container because in my opinion, the embedded container choice is made for microservices architecture. If you build a monolithic app with spring-boot it will be fast and make you happy but as the project grows, the memory usage also grows and bootstrapping will be hard. On the other hand, i think its perfect to create microservices with it, because its easy in terms of the time spend on code other than the business logic and fast in terms of response time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Post</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
        function send() {
            var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
            var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
             const data = {
                  "departmentName": name,
                  "departmentId": id,
                  "departmentAddress": address,
                  "departmentCode": code,
            };
            console.log(data);

 $.post({
  dataType : "json",
url:"api/postStudents",
data:JSON.stringify(data),
contentType : 'application/json',
});
}
function update() {
            var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
            var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
             const data = {
                  "departmentName": name,
                  "departmentId": id,
                  "departmentAddress": address,
                  "departmentCode": code,
            };
            console.log(data);

$.ajax({
  dataType : "json",
   type: 'PUT',
url:"api/updateStudents",
data:JSON.stringify(data),
contentType : 'application/json',
});
}


    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
         <div class="center-screen">

        <h1>I</h1>

        <h3>REGISTRATION</h3>
        <br>
        <text>Enter Student Name     : </text>
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" /></br>
        <br>
          <text>Enter Student Id     : </text>
        <input type="number" id="id" placeholder="id" /></br>
        <br>
         <text>Enter Student Address : </text>
        <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="address" \n/></br>
        <br>
         <text>Enter Student Code:</text>
        <input type="text" id="code" placeholder="code"/></br>
        <br>
        <button onclick="send()">Register</button>
        <button onclick="update()">Update</button></br>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).